# more than 1 checkbox need to hide or show div

Tags: javascript, checkbox, hide, show

whats wrong with this code??

http://jsfiddle.net/CLYC6/

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="test" name="test" value="test" />

<div id="test" style="display:none">
    test
</div>
```

js:

```
  $('.test').click(function() {
        if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#test").show();
        } else {
            $("#test").hide();
        }
    });
```

in future i want 3 checkboxes have to checked... not only one

Comment: You didn't include jQuery.

Comment: load jquery in your fiddle and it works...

Comment: thanks! can you help me with his code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the code, in jsFiddle, remember to load the jQuery lib on the left-hand side.

Comment: thanks! can you help me with his code? http://jsfiddle.net/CLYC6/20/